# Error Loading PyTorch Model: Setting from_tf=True

Tags: python, large-language-model, llama

I'm encountering an issue when trying to load a PyTorch model using a Text Generation Web UI, and I'm seeing the following error message:

```py
OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for  
‘models\georgesung_llama2_7b_chat_uncensored\pytorch_model-00003-of-00003.bin’ at 
‘models\georgesung_llama2_7b_chat_uncensored\pytorch_model-00003-of-00003.bin’. 

If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True.
```

I understand that I need to set `from_tf=True`, but I'm not sure where to do this. Can someone guide me on how to set this parameter correctly to resolve the issue?

Here's the full stack trace for reference:

```py
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py”, line 488, in load_state_dict

return torch.load(checkpoint_file, map_location=map_location)
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py”, line 797, in load

with _open_zipfile_reader(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py”, line 283, in init

super().__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive:  
  failed finding central directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py”, line 492, in load_state_dict

if f.read(7) == "version":

UnicodeDecodeError: ‘gbk’ codec can’t decode byte 0x80 in position 128:  
illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\modules\ui_model_menu.py”, line 194, in load_model_wrapper

shared.model, shared.tokenizer = load_model(shared.model_name, loader)
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\modules\models.py”, line 76, in load_model

output = load_func_map[loader](model_name)
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\modules\models.py”, line 205, in huggingface_loader

model = LoaderClass.from_pretrained(checkpoint, **params)
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py”, line 563, in from_pretrained

return model_class.from_pretrained(
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py”, line 3187, in from_pretrained

) = cls._load_pretrained_model(
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py”, line 3560, in _load_pretrained_model

state_dict = load_state_dict(shard_file)
File “F:\text-gen-webui\text-generation-webui-main\installer_files\env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py”, line 504, in load_state_dict

raise OSError(
OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for ‘models\georgesung_llama2_7b_chat_uncensored\pytorch_model-00003-of-00003.bin’ at ‘models\georgesung_llama2_7b_chat_uncensored\pytorch_model-00003-of-00003.bin’.   

If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True.
```

Comment: The first error message `RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive:  
  failed finding central directory` makes me think there are some issue with the loaded binary file `models\georgesung_llama2_7b_chat_uncensored\pytorch_model-00003-of-00003.bin`. Are you sure it is completed download and not corrupted? I think one way to confirm is retry the download of the file to see if it helps solve the issue. I would also be great if you can share the actual code you run to load the binary file